# Xamarin iOS - Set colour of button when pressed using PlatformEffect

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin, I have implemented a PlatformEffect for Android which changes the colour of a button when pressed. The implementation is like this:

```
[assembly:ResolutionGroupName("Framework")]
[assembly:ExportEffect(typeof(AndroidButtonClickEffect), "ButtonClickEffect")]
namespace Framework.Droid.Effects
{
    public class AndroidButtonClickEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            Control.Touch += Control_Touch;
        }

        private void Control_Touch(object sender, Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                SetColor(Color.LightBlue);
            }
            else if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                SetColor(Color.Blue);
            }

            var command = ButtonClickEffect.GetCommand(Element);
            command?.Execute(ButtonClickEffect.GetCommandParameter(Element));
        }

        private void SetColor(Color color)
        {
            Control.SetBackgroundColor(color);
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            Control.Touch -= Control_Touch;
        }
    }
}
```

For iOS however, I can't work how to capture the button press so that I can set the colour. Any ideas?

```
[assembly:ResolutionGroupName("Framework")]
[assembly:ExportEffect(typeof(IOsButtonClickEffect), "ButtonClickEffect")]
namespace Framework.iOS.Effects
{
    public class IOsButtonClickEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking for `Control.SetTitle(string, state)`. However, I'd prefer Bruno's suggestion over Effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply use Visual State Manager, no need for custom renderers.

```
<Button>
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   <Button>
```